# Что означают #define и %% в printf?

Tags: c, printf, препроцессор

Всем привет, я новичок в Си, можете объяснить пару вещей...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 1000 // Что означает эта строка, Что такое #define и "c чем его едят"
main() {
    int i,q;
    q = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) 
        if (rand()%100 % 2 == 0)
            q += 1;
    printf("%.2f%%\n", (float)q/N * 100); // Зачем нужен такой вывод "%.2f%%"?
}
```

Что такое #define и "c чем его едят"?(Это вторая строчка кода)

Что выводит printf при строке форматирования "%.2f%%"? (последняя строчка)

Comment: `int main()`. Использование `rand()` требует `#include <stdlib.h>`. Использование `time()` требует `#include <time.h>`. И откуда возник вопрос про "Зачем нужен такой вывод"? Так а как же без вывода в программе-то?

Comment: меня интересовало то,почему там два процента стоят ,  эти вот:   2f%%

Comment: Ну так может именно так и надо было формулировать вопрос?

Comment: @Elvin зная ответ, переформулируйте вопрос, чтобы другие, столкнувшиеся с похожим вопросом, смогли найти ответ здесь.

Comment: Вроде же про это всё рассказывают в любом учебнике по Си?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#define` - это директива препроцессора, программы подготавливающей код программы на языке C/C++ к компиляции.

Директива `#define` служит для замены часто использующихся констант, ключевых слов, операторов или выражений некоторыми идентификаторами.

В вашем случае код, написанный вами будет заменен на:

```
main() {
    int i,q;
    q = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i=0; i<1000; i++) 
        if (rand()%100 % 2 == 0)
            q += 1;
    printf("%.2f%%\n", (float)q/1000 * 100);
}
```

Более сложный пример для понимания:

```
#define  MAX(x,y) ((x)>(y))?(x):(y)

Эта директива заменит фрагмент

             t=MAX(i,s[i]);

на фрагмент

             t=((i)>(s[i])?(i):(s[i]);
```

Что касается `printf`, то первым аргументом является строка формата вывода.

`%.2f%%` разбивается на 2 части:

- %.2f - десятичное число с плавающей точкой с двумя знаками после запятой
- %% - это знак %

Answer (score 0):

define - это директива препроцессора. Дословно можно перевести, как "заменить". Именно в этом примере, используется для объявления константы N.
p.s.: это, так сказать, олдскульный способ объявления констант. В процессе компиляции программы, первым звеном выступает препроцессор. Он заменит все N на 1000 в данном файле. Вообще, для этих целей, лучше использовать оператор const.

"%.2f%%"- это спец. символы для формирования выходной строки. Более подробно http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/printf

Comment: Язык в данном случае - С. В языке С используется именно `#define`, а не `const`, и абсолютно ничего "олдскульного" в этом нет. В языке С `const` не работает в качестве заменителя `#define`. Здесь бы `const` сработало, но в общем случае - нет.